# Lost files when doing a git stash - Permission Denied

Tags: git

I'm in panic mode. I created a bigger commit than I should have really. I am on WSL2 using VS Code, running Ubunutu on a Windows machine. I did a git stash using the UI but forgot to include untracked changes. This is all fine, it created a stash with my tracked changes. Then I thought, ah I'll just stash my untracked changes too. I go ahead and try and do a stash (include untracked) and I get a permission denied error. However, all my untracked files have disappeared! How do I get these back? What the heck happened here? It was 2 days worth of work... (I know, I should have commited earlier)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the changes were there it just didn't show in the VS Code UI. All I had to do was apply the stash.

Comment: Glad you figured things out!

Comment: I always try to make small commits throughout the day, so I never lose much work! Like whenever I add a bit of new functionality or write some functions or something I'll commit

Comment: Another great example of why non-git-itself tools will always be able support less features than git does it itself today. Note that `git stash list` and `git stash show` are your true friends here. And terminal also is.